# Handling concurrent tasks

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have multiple concurrent tasks, all of them trying to check record existance, then, if not exist, will insert one.

Unfortunately, I end up with duplicate writing to the record into DB, as it seems that all of tasks decides that the record does not exist at the same time, then all of them do insertion.

The desired behavior, is that I got the insertion only once, and then, other tasks would recognize the existence of just inserted record.

Here is my attempt:

```
alias MyApp.Parent, as: Parent
alias MyApp.Repo, as: Repo
changeset = Parent.changeset(%Parent{}, model)

case Repo.all(from p in Parent, where: p.mobile_number == ^model.mobile_number) do

    [] ->
    #does not exist
      case Repo.insert_or_update(changeset) do
        {:ok, %MyApp.Parent{ id: parent_id }} -> parent_id
        error_message -> nil
      end


    [parent_get_by|t] ->
    #already exist
    %MyApp.Parent{ id: parent_id }= parent_get_by
        parent_id

end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `UNIQUE INDEX` in your database for the `mobile_number` field. It will be more efficient (you'll only have to do one query to the database) and you are guaranteed that the database can never ever have a duplicate value for that field in the table.

You'll need to do three things:

1. Add a [`unique_index`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#unique_index/3) to the table using a migration.
2. Add a call to [`unique_constraint`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3) in your changeset function.
3. In your controller, just do `Repo.insert(changeset)`. If the field is duplicated, you'll get `{:error, changeset}` back with the error message in `changeset.errors`.

Comment: so, then when I get an error, I will read using the `mobile_number ` ?

Comment: If you want to get the existing record back if one exists, you can do `Repo.get_by(Parent, mobile_number: model.mobile_number)` later.

Comment: what about using `insert_or_update` ? then, it will simply update if it does exist and returns back the record, is that better than using `get_by` for existing record?

Comment: Just note that if you use this approach, you will need to check that the error is in `changeset.errors`. Unfortunately it is also possible that your insert could have failed for unrelated issues. So you will HAVE to check the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine.

But when you can't enforce a unique index, you have two choices. First is using a lock, to prevent processes querying db at the same time. See [elixir_locker](https://github.com/tsharju/elixir_locker) for an example of this.

Another way is to serialize the requests. This means, you will have a process, preferably a `GenServer`, that will do the `SELECT+INSERT`. Then have you processes send a message to this, instead of querying db themselves. This makes the requests run after one another, and only the first request will insert, others will read. Of course, this process may become a bottleneck itself, if you have a lot of requests.